# How to have text wrap or scroll in UITableView section header?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, word-wrap

I'm trying to get the text in a section header of a UITable view to wrap and/or scroll.

I've tried this:

```
// support line break mode for multiline 
headerLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;

// 0 means any number of lines - necessary for multiline
headerLabel.numberOfLines = 0;

// fit the text  
[headerLabel sizeToFit];
```

but no luck.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you set the height of the header using

`-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section`

Answer (score 1):

Try this sample in `viewForHeaderInSection`:

```
 UIView* customView = [[UIView alloc] init];
 UILabel * headerLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
 headerLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
 headerLabel.opaque = YES;
 headerLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

 headerLabel.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

 headerLabel.shadowColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0f/255.0f green:0.0f/255.0f blue:0.0f/255.0f alpha:0.25f];
 headerLabel.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0f, -1.0f);

 headerLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16];
 headerLabel.frame = CGRectMake(10.0, 0.0, 232.0,40.0);

 headerLabel.numberOfLines=2;
 headerLabel.text=[self.keys objectAtIndex:section];

 [customView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.64f green:0.68f blue:0.72f alpha:1.0f]];
 [customView addSubview:headerLabel];

 return  customView;
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as the label goes, thats all you need to do to get it to work.  One question/suggestion, you are doing this to a label in the tableView's `– tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:`  method, right?